# Screen Size resolution for Phonegap application?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making an phone gap android application for screen size 3.5 inches to 5.3 inches but screen resolution is creating problem in creating UI.Can anybody help that for which resolution i will create my UI which is applicable to all screen size for 3.5 to 5.3 inches??
Please help me..Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to make a fluid layout using phonegap. Try to use percentages and relative mesures.
Also have in mind that in a mobile application you have to account for pixel density and etc.

See the viewport tag also, the following will make a non resizing, full screen application:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use media queries for that. Fetch the device resolution to a variable on deviceready and pass this to the media queries. Use of percentage and relative measures are also helpful.